# IP*Works SSH PublicKey Auth with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I'm trying to get IP*Works SSH / Sexec with AuthMode certificate, better PublicKey, to work. Everything works fine when I'm using simple user / Password combination.

My code for PublicKey:

```
    private static void DoSExec()
    {
        var sexec = new Sexec
        {
            SSHUser = "abc",
            SSHHost = "someserver",
            SSHPort = 22,
            SSHAuthMode = SexecSSHAuthModes.amPublicKey,
            SSHCert = new Certificate(@"c:\work\key.pem"),
            SSHEncryptionAlgorithms = "aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc"
        };
        sexec.Config("SSHMacAlgorithms=hmac-sha1");
        sexec.Config("SSHAcceptServerHostKeyFingerPrint=c9:e4:53:46:19:e7:58:ec:a7:3d:29:cc:42:87:f5:a5");
        sexec.OnStdout += SexecOnOnStdout;
        sexec.OnConnected += SexecOnConnected;
        sexec.OnError += SexecOnError;
        sexec.OnDisconnected += SexecOnDisconnected;
        sexec.OnStderr += SexecOnStderr;
        try
        {
            sexec.SSHLogon(host, port);
            if (sexec.Connected)
            {
                sexec.Execute("ls");
                if (sexec.ExitStatus != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sexec.ErrorMessage);
                }
                sexec.DoEvents();
                sexec.SSHLogoff();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Clientconfiguration of IP*Works SSH lib is exactly the same as SSH is configured on server side.

The connection itself is working well. The server tells us that there is a connection to SSH via my client. The connection is up until the client is sending the SSHLogoff()-signal.

The problem: the Execute()-method is doing.... NOTHING !

Any ideas what went wrong?

Thank you so much.

Best regards, Andreas